# Slope of main sequence in HR diagram

Tags: astrophysics, stars, stellar-physics, stellar-evolution

In the HR diagram, what causes the change of slope (more flattened) around the area marked with $X$? This corresponds to luminosity of $\sim 1 L_{\odot}$ and temperature $~6000-8000 K$

[image: HR diagram]

Comment: Please put axis labels on the plot and indicate whether they are logarithmic or not.